# Didn't find class on path: DexPathList after ndk setup , minSdk > = 21 ,

Tags: android, android-ndk, classnotfoundexception, runtimeexception, android-multidex

I'm working on an app which has to be linked to NDK. minSdk 21. So no multidex implemented, just  multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig

Before being linked to ndk everything was running well, since it's installed the error **Didn't find class ...App  on path: DexPathList** is occuring.

Also I thought removing the app path from the < application > in the manifest will result in a run. At last I get this error : **Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer**

has the ndk setup any influence on the application class ?

Help :)

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.moondev.seebrizrevival">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />




<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    android:hasCode="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">



    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


    <activity android:name=".activity.SearchActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ActivityAdvancedSettings"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activity.CheckIfUserAlreadyConnectedActivity" />


    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
        android:value="https://parseapi.back4app.com/" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/rubenApiKey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="@string/rubenClientKey" />


    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
    </provider>

    <service
        android:name="com.raygun.raygun4android.services.CrashReportingPostService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:process=":crashreportingpostservice" />

    <service
        android:name="com.raygun.raygun4android.services.RUMPostService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:process=":rumpostservice" />
    <!--        <meta-data android:name="com.raygun.raygun4android.apikey"-->
    <!--            android:value="@string/apiKey" />-->
    <!--        <service-->
    <!--            android:name="com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android."-->
    <!--            android:exported="false"-->
    <!--            android:process=":raygunpostservice" />-->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.mindscapehq.android.raygun4android.apikey"
        android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />


</application>
```

Gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.moondev.seebrizrevival"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries = false
    }


}

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
    }
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
    }
```

Comment: I had similar problem in the past please add  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'  in your dependency in gradle (app module)

Comment: The project is under androidx and I tried this multiple times as well as :
extending MultiDex  from the Application class, MultiDex.install(this), and to change the app name in the manifest like  <application >android:name = "androidx.multidex.MultidexApplication" </application>